# paypal adds extra tax on paypal website

Tags: php, paypal

I have an issue with a clients website where he reports this issue is happening randomly.
It seems that Paypal sometimes adds the TAX again on their side.

I printed the url that the store redirects to after clicking purchase on our checkout page:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=email@me.com&return=returnurl&cancel_return=cancelurl&rm=2¤cy_code=CAD&lc=CAD&bn=Mysite&no_note=1&charset=utf-8¬ify_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2F%3Fwpsc_action%3Dgateway_notification%26gateway%3Dwpsc_merchant_paypal_standard&invoice=2081379006142&upload=1&cmd=_ext-enter&redirect_cmd=_cart&handling_cart=0.00&item_name_1=Your+Shopping+Cart&amount_1=115.07&quantity_1=1&shipping_1=0&shipping2_1=0&handling_1=0&tax_cart=13.24
```

The total that we show on our site is 115.07 That is the total ammount the user has to pay including tax. But when i get to Paypal site using the url (edited some values) it adds tax again. It looks like this:

```
DescriptionsAmount
Your Shopping Cart $115.07 Item price: $115.07 Quantity: 1 Item total $115.07 Tax $13.24 Total $128.31 USD
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got Sales Tax rules configured in your PayPal account profile, but then you're also including it in your total that you're sending to PayPal.  If you're going to include the tax in your total you need to disable the tax configuration in your profile.